# Using VMWare Converter to clone a Win7 VM

Tags: windows-7, vmware-server, sysprep, vmware-converter

I have a win7 VM running in VMWare Server that I built from scratch. I wanted to use this VM as a baseline and use Converter to clone it. However while using the Converter tool, it says it can't find sysprep. I need to be able to reconfigure the SID and machine name, etc. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the newest converter 4.3 which now supports Windows 7 OS. Great article here:
[Windows 7 - vCenter converter](http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2010/09/p2v-windows-7-convert-a-window-7-pc-to-a-virtual-machine.html)

Answer (score 2):

You just basically need to download sysprep and tell VMware convertor where it is on the guest system. It's a pretty straightforward process. More detailed instructions are easily google-able, but here's one for you:

http://vmetc.com/2009/08/18/how-to-add-sysprep-to-vmware-vcenter-for-vm-customizations-vmware-converter-also/

Comment: i've used that process successfully in the past for Win2k3. This question refers specifically to Win7, as the documentation at http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1005593 doesn't mention win7 and leads one to believe that sysprep capabilities should be built-in, since it says as much for Vista and Win2k8